# OpenVPN MAC filtering - adding multiple MACs?

Tags: openvpn, mac-address

I was following this [OpenVPN document](https://docs.openvpn.net/wp-content/uploads/OpenVPN-Access-Server-post_auth-MAC-address-checking.pdf), and I've managed to enable the MAC filtering feature. How do I add multiple MACs for a single user to the database?

Example command I would use to replace the registered MAC:

```
# ./sacli -u "exampleuser" -k "pvt_hw_addr" -v "00:01:02:ab:cd:12" UserPropPut
```

Comment: This question is better suited on SuperUser, as it's not about security, but about configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the script which does the MAC checking, in its current state it doesn't appear to be possible to do this. However, just some slight modification would be necessary in order to enable this behaviour, as really the script is just reading a value and comparing the local MAC to it:

```
        if hw_addr:
            hw_addr_save = proplist.get('pvt_hw_addr') # saved MAC addr property
            if hw_addr_save:
                if hw_addr_save != hw_addr:
                    error = "The hardware MAC address reported by this VPN client does not match the registered MAC address."
```

You could simply save a comma-separated list into this property, and change this part of the script to split the saved `pvt_hw_addr` property into a list, and check that the local MAC is contained within it.

Having said that, OpenVPN is designed to support certificate-based authentication, which does a good job of authenticating hardware. MAC addresses are easily spoofed, so this may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks James, I am no programmer. Would you be able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

cd /usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts

#./sacli -u "exampleuser" -k "pvt_hw_addr**2**" -v "ef:cd:ba:03:02:01" UserPropPut

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).